# DynamoDB Data Modeling - Dropping Consideration

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, data-modeling

Consider a Measurement table having the following (simplified) data:

> - Device ID
> - Timestamp
> - Measurement

Consider also the following requirements:

> 1. Number of devices and measurements are very big
> 2. Measurements are inserted one by one for each device (and not in bulks)
> 3. Typical "select" will query based on Device ID for certain period of time
> 4. Old data should be dropped

If I understand DynamoDB concepts correctly, this is how I should model this table:

> - Hash key: Device ID (for inserts and selects efficiency)
> - Range key: Timestamp (same as above)
> - Designated table for each period (to drop tables instantly)

Does is sound good? Any other suggestions?

Thank you!

Comment: It looks like you have this figured out. Your design sounds good to me.